# Refresh div every seconds with ajax and show new div with existing div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, html

I have 1 web page where I want to display list of users joined to my web site and connections between them.

I have users and connections between them:

```
 var data=[
           {
              "Id": 38,
               "Connections":[39,40],
               "Name":"ABc"
          },
           {
              "Id": 39,
               "Connections":[40],
               "Name":"pqr"
           },
           {
               "Id": 40,
               "Connections":[],
               "Name":"lmn"
           }]
```

In the above example user with `Id:38` is connected to `user 39 and 40` and `user 39 is connected to user 40 and user 40` is already connected to `user 39 and user 38 so user 40 Connection array is blank`.

I have a web service which I will fires every 1-2 seconds to display newly joined users on this page and new connection between existing users which I have stored in my table and this web service will fetch all users along with their connections.

So at first my page will load but after then my page will not refresh and new users should be displayed and new connections should be connected with AJAX call to my web service.

So far I have been successfully manage to display users and connection between them but now stuck with auto refresh div in 1-2 seconds so that new connections are made without making previous connections.

Right now what happening is when I refresh my div previous connections are made again.

I am using this plugin:[Jquery-connections.js](https://github.com/musclesoft/jquery-connections)

This is one demo which I made; please ignore js which i have kept in html because that is plugin (Jquery-connections.js):[JS bin Demo](http://output.jsbin.com/bofiyokode)

Comment: When ever you fetch new data and if there is difference between new data and existing data you can recreate or add new items into view containing div, and I hope there will be a option to add new connection in `jQuery Connection js` plugin. what is blocking  in that?

Comment: May be this http://arborjs.org/ plugin will help to implement it fast.

Comment: @DipakChandranP:ok that i can do like add new data to existing data but if you see my code i am looping every div for moments that is where the problem is.

Comment: @DipakChandranP:Have you seen my js bin and check the output and code??

Comment: You are looping through all the div to find out the exact node-element and to modifying it, right? I am not able to understand what each js functionality exactly trying to do, can you please add some comments on each function.

Comment: @DipakChandranP:Yeah thats right

Comment: You can create `div` with `id` value as `userId`, so that next time when you have the new data, instead of looping through all the `div` in the `#container` you can directly fetch it by the `id` using `document.getElementById` and modify it, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110461/discussion-between-learning-and-dipak-chandran-p).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the discussion points we have reached to resolve the issues :

- replace div elements with canvas to ease and faster rendering.
- use Third party js library for rendering nodes and edges into canvas.

Comment: sorry i quit using canvas as it would require lots of code refactoring

Comment: And web application slowness?

Comment: animation still stucks a little that issue is still there but canvas was taking lots of time so i have quit using it.Thank you so much for all your guidance throughout the task.It really means alot otherwise i would have definetely struggling with it