# Getting inappropriate json data struture

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have this data:**Users**

```
UserId   Name
 42      Abc  
 43      Pqr
 44      lmn
 45      xyz
```

**Mappings**:

```
MappingId  User1  User2  
1           42    43
2           42    44 
3           43    44
```

Now i have 1 web service which i fires every seconds to get users and users connection and return json data in this format:

```
var data =
        [{
            "UserId": 42,
            "Name": "Abc",
            "Connections": [43,44]
        }, {
            "UserId": 43,
            "Name": "Pqr",
            "Connections": [44]
        }, {
            "UserId": 44,
            "Name": "Lmn",
            "Connections": []
        }, {
            "UserId": 45,
            "Name": "xyz",
            "Connections": []
        }];
```

Basically the purpose of this web service is to always fetch new users and new connections of existing users and that is why i am firing this
web service in each seconds.

So my conditions is like this (skip already fetch users and fetch new users if there) or (skip already fetch connections and fetch new 
connections of existing users) but json data structure should be same.

So that on each web service call either i get all new users or if new users are not there then fetch existing users whose new connections are made.

**Use Case 1**:

```
UserId   Name
 42      Abc  
 43      Pqr
```

**output json**:

```
var data =
        [{
            "UserId": 42,
            "Name": "Abc",
            "Connections":[]
        },
         {
            "UserId": 43,
            "Name": "xyz",
            "Connections":[]
        }];
```

**Use Case 2**:
If connections are made between user 42 and user 43 then:
**output json**:

```
var data =
        [{
            "UserId": 42,
            "Name": "Abc",
            "Connections":[43]
        }];
```

**Use Case 3**:New user enters:

```
UserId   Name
 42      Abc  
 43      Pqr
 44      lmn
```

**output json**:

```
var data =
        [{
            "UserId": 44,
            "Name": "Almn",
            "Connections":[]
        }];
```

**Use Case 4**:connections made between user 42 and 44:

```
var data =
        [{
            "UserId": 42,
            "Name": "Abc",
            "Connections":[42,44]
        }];
```

This is my code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetUsers([FromUri]Int32 skip = 0)    
        {
            var userBll = new UserBLL();
            var result = context.Users.ToList();
            var lists = new List<string>();
            var connectionsData = context.Mappings.ToList().OrderBy(t => t.CreatedDate.Value.Date).ThenBy(t => t.CreatedDate.Value.TimeOfDay).Skip(skip).Take(1);
            lists.Add(connectionsData.FirstOrDefault().User1 + "," + connectionsData.FirstOrDefault().User2);
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result.Select(r => new 
            {
                UserId=r.UserId,
                Name = r.FirstName + " " + r.LastName,
                Connections = lists
            }));
            return response;
        }
```

But getting below output with below input data:

```
UserId   Name
 42      Abc  
 43      Pqr
 44      lmn
 45      xyz


MappingId  User1  User2  
1           42    43

var data =
        [{
            "UserId": 42,
            "Name": "Abc",
            "Connections": [42,43]
        }, {
            "UserId": 43,
            "Name": "Pqr",
            "Connections": [42,43]
        }, {
            "UserId": 44,
            "Name": "Lmn",
            "Connections": [42,43]
        }, {
            "UserId": 45,
            "Name": "xyz",
            "Connections": [42,43]
        }];
```

Javascript Code:

```
var userList = [];
  function GetData() {
             $.getJSON('Url', {skip:userList.length} ,function (response) {
                updateUserList(response);
            });
        }

 function updateUserList(data) {
            if (JSON.stringify(userList).toString() != JSON.stringify(data).toString()) { //if old data is not same as new data
                userList = data;
            }
            else
            {
                setTimeout(GetData, 1000); //fire request every 1 seconds
            }
        }
```

**Note**:I don't have foreign key relationship.

Comment: You have a `ucontext` and a `context` - so the tables are held in separate databases or just two different contexts? Also, `connections` is not declared prior to be used to set the `Connections` property. But the crux of your problem is that you are not joining from `User` to `Mappings` so every `User` is displaying the same first record of `Mappings`.

Comment: @strickt01:Sorry that was a mistake and thanks for pointing out.Question updated.Please check

Comment: I know this is off topic, but I'd suggest looking into SignalR if you need real-time data broadcasting to javascript client. Pinging an API every second will be a problem in the future.

Comment: I'd say you need to modify your data model. Perhaps adding a new table (ex: `Activities`) that holds new logins and new connections between users. In that table, you could have a `Seen` bit field indicating whether this has been sent to your javascript client or not.

Comment: @FrancisDucharme:but i already have Mappings table and if you say i add new table Activities so when entry should be done in that table??

Comment: @Learning Everytime you have a new login or mapping, insert a row in `Activities`, with `Seen` defaulting to 0. `Activities` could have a `Regarding` field, in which you stick the ID of the Mapping or `Login` and a `ActivitType` field, telling you whether it's a new mapping/login. The API you'd ping every second would be one getting info from `Activities`.

Comment: @FrancisDucharme:I am trying to achieve this.See this question this what exactly i want to do:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36906272/refresh-div-every-seconds-with-ajax-and-show-new-div-with-existing-div?noredirect=1#comment61376702_36906272

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the type of `Connections` is `IEnumerable<int>`;

```
context.Users.Select(r => new
            {
                UserId =r.UserId,
                Name = r.FirstName + " " + r.LastName,
                Connections = context.Mappings.OrderBy(t => t.CreatedDate.Value).Skip(skip).Where(m => m.User1 == r.UserId).Select(m => m.User2)
                    .Concat(context.Mappings.OrderBy(t => t.CreatedDate.Value).Skip(skip).Where(m => m.User2 == r.UserId).Select(m => m.User1))
            });
```

Comment: Sorry i dont have foreign key set up and so no navigation property

Comment: If you would have notice i am passing old records counter i.e userlist.length when calling my web service in javascript

Comment: OK, I've removed the use of navigation properties and used a `Where` clause. I've also added your `Skip` although I'm not sure this will give you the results you desire and may be inefficient..

Comment: isnt this will fetch already fetched users too.please see my use cases

Comment: That's the point I made earlier about you having no means of working out the new users. You have this `Skip` on the `Mappings` but not on the `Users` but can't use one variable for both. As @Francis-Ducharme has explained you need a means of auditing when a new user or connection is made so that when your service is called you can work out what has changed since it was last called. I'd agree that pinging your service is hugely inefficient so SignalR would be a good alternative in this use case. You need at the very least to persist in both tables when that user/connection was made.

Comment: A `rowversion` (are you using SQL Server?) is probably the best option in this case. You can then pass this back in each time to work out new records.

Comment: i have done this and just wanted to share with you so that you can suggest me if something is wrong